# Why does Python not recognize filesize of CSV immediately after unzipping?

Tags: python, csv, zip

I have a python (v2.7.2 on OSX Lion) script that unzips an archive into a new folder, and then finds a csv within those files. It then attempts to open the CSV and read through it.

This was all working as expected, up to a point. The problem i have been running into is that, when executed as described above, at times the script perceives the file to be 0 length. But when I run the same code from the command line interpreter, it sees the file correctly. Can anyone help me understand what the reason for this might be?

Pseudo Code:

```
# unzip the archive, locating csvfile along the way...

statinfo = os.stat(unzip_dir + "/" + csvfile)
    print statinfo
```

output from the above snippet:

```
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5318966, st_dev=234881026L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=80, st_size=0, st_atime=1329963124, st_mtime=1329963124, st_ctime=1329963124)
```

(notice st_size=0!)

Now I go directly to the python command line and enter:

```
import os

statinfo = os.stat("/Users/Me/Testdir/test.csv")

print statinfo
```

Output from the above snippet:

```
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=5318966, st_dev=234881026L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=80, st_size=290, st_atime=1329963124, st_mtime=1329963124, st_ctime=1329963124)
```

As we see, st_size is now seen by Python.

I'm stumped. Any ideas? I can post more code if necessary. Thank you.

Comment: Could you try something like a sleep-loop to your original script? Like try opening the file, while the size is 0, sleep a second and do this a couple of times before giving up. I think this is a filesystem/os issue, best solved with a sleep cycle that actually knows that the file size is not zero, for example by probing the archive for filesizes, and then looping/sleeping forever while the OS gets its stuff in order.

Comment: I did try a sleep between the unzip and the csv. Didn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just forgot to flush.

Comment: That was it. Forgot to flush. Thanks a million.